# Can't install any packages

Tags: debian, apt

Can't install any packages on Debian 7.2 through the `apt-get`

```
root@sandbox:~# apt-get install curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 curl : Depends: libcurl3 (= 7.26.0-1+wheezy3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


root@sandbox:~# apt-cache policy curl
curl:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 7.26.0-1+wheezy3
  Version table:
     7.26.0-1+wheezy3 0
        500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian-security/ wheezy/updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://mirror.mephi.ru/debian-security/ wheezy/updates/main amd64 Packages


root@sandbox:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib

#deb http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian-security/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian-security/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
#deb http://mirror.mephi.ru/debian-security/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://mirror.mephi.ru/debian-security/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
```

`apt-get -f install` also does not work

Comment: Perhaps your `yandex.ru` mirror is not complete?It will be slower but what happens if you use `deb packages.debian.org wheezy/updates main contrib non-free` instead?

Comment: @terdon Turn off mirrors. `deb http://packages.debian.org wheezy/updates main contrib non-free` raise error: `E: GPG error: http://packages.debian.org wheezy/updates Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2` on `apt-get update`

Comment: Sorry, my bad, that should have been `http://http.debian.net/debian` but never mind, I think Martin is right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `sources.list` is broken - it is missing the "stable" part of the repository which contains the bulk of all Debian packages. You've only added the "wheezy/updates" part which only contains updates for some packages from "stable".

It should instead probably look something like this (generated with http://debgen.simplylinux.ch/ , assuming you are located in Russia):

```
deb http://ftp.ru.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
```

Comment: Yep, you right. Thx.